# Using Simple Injector with EF in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

In my wpf app I need to be able to read/write data from specific table/tables, so, as I'm using `SimpleInjector` to use all services and stuff.

So, basically I want to be able to use repository in some of my services.

First I found this [How to use Simple injector, Repository and Context - code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594391/how-to-use-simple-injector-repository-and-context-code-first)

And decided to do something like that:

Entry point:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Container appContainer;
    private void AppStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        appContainer = new Container();
        appContainer.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ThreadScopedLifestyle();

        appContainer.RegisterSingleton<INLogger, LoggerNlog>();

        //some of services registration

        appContainer.Register<DbContext>(() =>
        {
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            return new ExcelSlicerContext(connectionString);
        }, Lifestyle.Scoped);

        appContainer.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        appContainer.Register<IMainAppSerivce, SlicerMainService>();
        appContainer.Register<MainViewModel>();

        appContainer.Verify();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        ConfigureContainer();

        using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(appContainer))
        {
            var viewModel = appContainer.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();

            var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

Example of service:

```
public class SlicerMainService : IMainAppSerivce
{

    private INLogger _nLogger;
    //  ...
    private IRepository<FactModel> _dataFactRepository;

    public SlicerMainService(INLogger nLogger, IRepository<FactModel> dataFactRepository)
    {
        _nLogger = nLogger;
        //...
        _dataFactRepository = dataFactRepository;
    }

    //...
    public void TestWorkWithDb(int[] sheetIndexList)
    {
        var t = _dataFactRepository.Get(x => x.Row > 6).ToList();
    }

}
```

So, in this example, when it tries to get some data it simple says that `DbContext is disposed`.

I know it is because of in need to use scope like `using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(myContainer))` but is it good practice to pass container to some services? I doubt it.

Whats the way of properly inject `IRepository<T>` here?

Code for repositories & dbcontext:

```
 public class ExcelSlicerContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<FactModel> FactData { get; set; }

        public ExcelSlicerContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(
                new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ExcelSlicerContext>()
            );
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<FactModel>().ToTable("fact");
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
 public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    DbContext _context;
    DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetFirst(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity FindById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Create(TEntity item)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void CreateFromRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> itemList)
    {
        _dbSet.AddRange(itemList);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Update(TEntity item)
    {
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Remove(TEntity item)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void RemoveWhere(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        _dbSet.RemoveRange(_dbSet.Where(predicate).ToList());
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity item)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> itemList)
    {
        _dbSet.AddRange(itemList);
    }

    public void Save(bool recreateContext)
    {
        if (recreateContext)
        {
            RecreateContext();
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void RecreateContext()
    {
        var constring = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = new ExcelSlicerContext(constring);
        _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Interface for repository:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        void Create(TEntity item);
        void CreateFromRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> itemList);
        void Add(TEntity item);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> itemList);
        void Save(bool recreateContext);
        TEntity FindById(int id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Get();
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
        TEntity GetFirst(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
        void Remove(TEntity item);
        void RemoveWhere(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
        void Update(TEntity item);

    }
```

**UPD**

After I read the answer, which linked as duplicate I implemented things as it was implemeneted in the example, e.g.:

```
 public class ThreadScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    {
        private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> decorateeFactory;
        private readonly Container container;

        public ThreadScopedCommandHandlerDecorator(Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> decorateeFactory, Container container)
        {
            this.decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
            this.container = container;
        }

        public void Handle(TCommand command)
        {
            using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
            {
                var handler = decorateeFactory.Invoke();
                handler.Handle(command);

            }
        }
    }
```

Saving changes handler:

```
public class SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>: ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    {
        private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee;
        private DbContext db;

        public SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee, DbContext db)
        {
            this.decoratee = decoratee;
            this.db = db;
        }

        public void Handle(TCommand command)
        {
            this.decoratee.Handle(command);
            this.db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

as decorators and, as example, such a command:

```
 public class GetFactModelCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<GetFactModelCommand>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<FactModel> _factRepository;

        public GetFactModelCommandHandler(IRepository<FactModel> factRepository)
        {
            _factRepository = factRepository;
        }

        public void Handle(GetFactModelCommand command)
        {
            var data = _factRepository.Get(x => x.DocGuid == command.DocGuid);
        }
    }
```

But then I realized, that on every new action for every different entity I need to implement commands and command handlers!

It dozens and dozens of classes!

And also, how I could get results from command (I know I can make something like `ICommandHandler<Command, TResult>` and have filed there for store the result but... its not like `Command Pattern` should be implemented AFAIK

Is there any other way? 
Just implement some `IService` for particular entity?

Comment: Although the question is about winforms, the answer would be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808487/3294832

Comment: And apart from the question, I would suggest you rethink the `IRepository` interface. Most members can be easily extracted to extension methods, which makes the interface much smaller, thereby adhering to [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Comment: @Ric.Net hmm, is it only me or the solution for this question looks like overcomplicated? I mean, commands, decorator - is there way to make it more simple? Like just pass ` IRepository<FactModel> _dataFactRepository` and call `Save`?

Comment: @Ric.Net yep, thank you, I will)

Comment: > overcomplicated Well, when your application starts to grow you quickly find a lot of code duplication. With commands, every class has it's own responsibility and things like creating a scope, saving, transaction handling etc. will be there already (in a generic decorator). Things become quickly oversimplified when using commands. If you application won't grow and has a single use case, commands indeed could be overcomplicated, but it depends purely on that fact.

Comment: @Ric.Net yeah, I guess you right. Actually application is very simple and for temp purposes but I am not sure really (thats why instead of pure sql I decided to use ORM-stuff)

Comment: @Ric.Net I'm sorry, but I still don't get how in final example is participating `ThreadScopedCommandHandlerDecorator` ?

Comment: I would advise you to read the provided link and if this is not sufficient, ask a detailed question on this subject

Comment: @Ric.Net oh, well, I read but, I mean, in final code parts it's looks like (except for registrating things) `ThreadScopedCommandHandlerDecorator `  not involved or maybe I just misunderstanfing things. Will try to implement it as I see it anyway

Comment: @Ric.Net ahh I get it, I just wasnt know how it works with SimpleInjector

Comment: @Ric.Net oh thank you, sir, it working now! I'm sorry for all of the misunderstaing

Comment: @Ric.Net but now I got other connected questions. Please, can you review it?

Comment: Sure, post a link to your related question.

Comment: @Ric.Net it's in current question, but after UPD mark)

Comment: You really should move that to a new question.